# How to attach fancybox onto iframe that opens pdf file

Tags: javascript, iframe, fancybox

I have the following java code in script file

```
$(".various").fancybox({
                maxWidth    : 1035,
                maxHeight   : 850,
                fitToView   : false,
                width       : '70%',
                height      : '70%',
                autoSize    : false,
                closeClick  : false,
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none'
            });
```

The following

```
html = html
                        + "<li><a href=\""
                        + pdfUrl
                        + "\" onclick=\"trackFactsheetView("+surveyId+",\'pdf\')\" class=\".iframe\" data-fancybox-type=\"iframe\" >View Facts</a></li>";
```

...gives me

```
<a class=".iframe" data-fancybox-type="iframe" onclick="trackFactsheetView(44,'pdf')" href="public/filespool/0/44/US_Atlantic_East_Coast_Program-_USGS-2010.pdf">View Facts</a>
```

The `a` links do not get generated on document at load time. They get created on a dialog once an event is triggered.

However when I click on this link it opens the pdf file on browser and not in iframe.

Comment: Why not use fancybox as an iframe?

Comment: @Sankalp I am trying to but it is not working for me. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: .iframe should be iframe

Comment: It does not work. Images work for me but they use class `fancybox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed class to `fancybox`. It is working now